# After opening PSD from the internet images became huge

Tags: adobe-photoshop, file-size, bug

After I downloaded a PSD and worked with it for a bit I noticed that trivial JPEG's and PNG's are HUGE...

Is there a setting it toggled or maybe it's a virus?

This is one image

[image: huge image]

Notice it's huge 876kb!

If I copy and paste it then save I get the same size.

If I exit photoshop. Open it again and then paste the image I get this:

[image: 18kb version]

Which is 18kb for the exact same image. Notice that reopening and resaving the original is still broken after a photoshop restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this sucks and seems to be a **SERIOUS** Adobe bug!!!

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1596435

You open a file and then there is no longer a way to remove the meta data other than deleting Adobe preferences...